# Sort values from get_field_objects() - ACF

Tags: php, sorting, advanced-custom-fields

I have several custom fields in every custom post type called "product", I grab those fields with `get_field_objects()` this way:

```
$fields = get_field_objects();


if ( !empty($fields) ){
    echo "<dl class='clearfix'>";
    foreach ( $fields as $field ){
       if (empty($field['value']))  continue;
       echo "<dt>".$field['label']."</dt><dd>".$field['value']."</dd>";
       echo '<br class="clear">';
    }
    echo "</dl>";
}
```

My client wants to be able to sort the the fields by the menu order (so he can just drag and drop in the plugin area).
But I didn't see any ordering documentations here- http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_objects/

Right know the order is- the field that create last is the last one.
Is there any good solution for this?

Comment: You can drag and drop the order of the fields from within the Edit Field Group section - although that may not be what you require here. What I mean is that you can re-order the fields by drag and drop when you are creating the field group - see: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/creating-a-field-group/

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to make use of the [repeater](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/) type of acf.

That way, you client will be able to add as many fields as he require, and sort them like he want by drag and dropping them.

If you need to know the "type" of each field (to change the style for example), you could add a select field (in your repeater field) with all your types of field.

You would then have something like this :

[image]

And something like this to display the fields :

```
<?php $fields = get_field('fields'); ?>
<?php if ( !empty($fields) ) : ?>
    <dl class='clearfix'>
        <?php foreach ( $fields as $field ) : ?>
            <dt><?= $field['label']; ?></dt><dd><?= $field['value']; ?></dd>
            <br class="clear">
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
<?php endif; ?>
```